# xQuery group output by category

Tags: xpath, xquery

I have another little problem with xQuery/xPath. For my homework i need to output the product range by branch and product category, where the output should only contain those branches (filiale), that have products (produkt and prodInSortiment) of every category (kategorie).
For the XML data please see the URL provided in the code.

While this gives me the right amount of products for each branch, i need to group it further by product category:

```
declare context item := doc("https://etutor.dke.uni-linz.ac.at/etutor/XML?id=1");
let $filialen := //filiale,
    $sortiment := //prodInsortiment,
    $produkte := //produkt,
    $kategorien := distinct-values(//produkt/kategorie)

for $f in $filialen
    let $s := $f//prodInSortiment
    let $scat := distinct-values($produkte[@ean = $s/ean]/kategorie)
    let $filsort := $produkte[@ean = $s/ean]/@ean
    let $catcount := count($scat)
    where $catcount = count(distinct-values($kategorien))

return
<filiale filialeNr="{$f/@filNr}"> 
{for $fs in $filsort return <ean>{$fs}</ean>
}
</filiale>
```

This is my approach of grouping it further, but it returns every product for every category(kategorie) in every branch(filiale):

```
declare context item := doc("https://etutor.dke.uni-linz.ac.at/etutor/XML?id=1");
let $filialen := //filiale,
    $sortiment := //prodInsortiment,
    $produkte := //produkt,
    $kategorien := distinct-values(//produkt/kategorie)

for $f in $filialen
    let $s := $f//prodInSortiment
    let $scat := distinct-values($produkte[@ean = $s/ean]/kategorie)
    let $filsort := $produkte[@ean = $s/ean]/@ean
    let $catcount := count($scat)
    where $catcount = count(distinct-values($kategorien))

return
<filiale filialeNr="{$f/@filNr}"> 
{for $cat in $scat return 
<prodGruppe val = "{$cat}">
{for $fs in $filsort return <ean>{$fs}</ean>
}
</prodGruppe>
}
</filiale>
```

The result should look like this (this is the correct output for filiale "1"):

```
<filiale filialeNr="1">
<prodGruppe val="Pflege">
<ean>0-666-4567-2-22</ean>
<ean>0-777-4997-2-43</ean>
<ean>0-456-4887-3-22</ean>
<ean>0-55-48567-16-2</ean>
</prodGruppe>
<prodGruppe val="Ersatz">
<ean>1-626-7767-2-99</ean>
<ean>1-256-7700-2-00</ean>
<ean>1-333-7788-2-31</ean>
<ean>2-446-7240-9-15</ean>
<ean>9-396-7510-9-00</ean>
</prodGruppe>
<prodGruppe val="Audio">
<ean>7-2881-760-3-70</ean>
<ean>5-2671-955-5-55</ean>
<ean>1-4444-652-8-88</ean>
<ean>3-1111-654-3-99</ean>
</prodGruppe>
<prodGruppe val="Sonstiges">
<ean>6-581-1766-3-45</ean>
<ean>6-231-4777-3-15</ean>
<ean>4-1161-730-3-88</ean>
<ean>0-4381-880-7-00</ean>
<ean>5-6661-000-0-00</ean>
</prodGruppe>
```

Since there is an upcoming mid-term exam, I'm not just asking for a solution, I'm also interested in possible simpler ways to achieve the correct output.
Thanks in advance for any helpful information!

Comment: XQuery 3.0 and 3.1 have a `group by` clause (https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#id-group-by) for FLOWR expressions that is meant to be used for such tasks. Are you restricted to XQuery 1.0 or why do you try to solve that with the help of `distinct-values`?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with all options that are available. Therefore i decided to go this way. Seemed the easiest for me. Your rewrite works as intended, thank you.
And there is no limit to XQuery 1.0. Working with basex atm.
Didn't think about group by in return part...
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have XQuery 3's `group-by` clause (https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#id-group-by) you can rewrite the last return to

```
return
<filiale filialeNr="{$f/@filNr}"> 
{
    for $prod in $s
    group by $cat := $produkte[@ean = $prod/ean]/kategorie
    return 
        <prodGruppe val = "{$cat}">
        {
            $prod/ean
        }
        </prodGruppe>
}
</filiale>
```

I think.